# language-check OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, languagetool

I've encountered a problem when attempting to use the `language-tool` package for Python. This same error also occurs when using the `language-check` package. It seems apparent to me that the issue has got to do with the `language-tool` package itself, as Java itself and my LanguageTool server are both functioning.

I'm on Windows 10 running Java 10. I also tried with Java 8, which is known to work fully with LanguageTool. A different error was raised in a similar fashion with Java 8.

LanguageTool itself DOES work from the command line and the GUI also works. I successfully tested the LanguageTool server from my browser at `http://localhost:8081/v2/check?language=en-US&text=my+text` as well.

In addition to reinstalling the `language-tool` package, I've attempted to initiate my own LanguageTool Java server for Python in three ways. All three return the same error in Python. The first way is by running the following code from within a Jupyter Notebook:

```
import language_tool as lt
text = "This is very interesting text"
lt.correct(text, (lt.LanguageTool("en-US")).check(text))
```

This returns a very detailed error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-9112af7b3bc6> in <module>()
      1 text = "This is very interesting text"
----> 2 lt.correct(text, (lt.LanguageTool("en-US")).check(text))

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in __init__(self, language, motherTongue)
    186     def __init__(self, language=None, motherTongue=None):
    187         if not self._server_is_alive():
--> 188             self._start_server_on_free_port()
    189         if language is None:
    190             try:

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in _start_server_on_free_port(cls)
    321             cls._url = "http://{}:{}".format(cls._HOST, cls._port)
    322             try:
--> 323                 cls._start_server()
    324                 break
    325             except ServerError:

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in _start_server(cls)
    345                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    346                 universal_newlines=True,
--> 347                 startupinfo=startupinfo
    348             )
    349             # Python 2.7 compatibility

c:\program files\python37\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    754                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    755                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 756                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    757         except:
    758             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

c:\program files\python37\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1153                                          env,
   1154                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1155                                          startupinfo)
   1156             finally:
   1157                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

The second way is by initiating a server via command-line by running `java -cp languagetool-server.jar org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer --port 8081`, then running the same code as about from a python terminal in the same window. This returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._start_server_on_free_port()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py", line 323, in _start_server_on_free_port
    cls._start_server()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py", line 347, in _start_server
    startupinfo=startupinfo
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

The third way I've attempted to initiate a server is by using the LanguageTool GUI and running the code about from a Notebook, which returns the same verbose output.

Finally, I tried with Java 8. In a notebook the following error was returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in get_languages()
    489     try:
--> 490         languages = cache["languages"]
    491     except KeyError:

KeyError: 'languages'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in _get_root(cls, url, data, num_tries)
    309             try:
--> 310                 with urlopen(url, data, cls._TIMEOUT) as f:
    311                     return ElementTree.parse(f).getroot()

c:\program files\python37\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 

c:\program files\python37\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 

c:\program files\python37\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

c:\program files\python37\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 

c:\program files\python37\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:

c:\program files\python37\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-116c54f6eff2> in <module>()
      1 import language_tool as lt
      2 text = "This is very interesting text"
----> 3 lt.correct(text, (lt.LanguageTool("en-US")).check(text))

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in __init__(self, language, motherTongue)
    192             except ValueError:
    193                 language = FAILSAFE_LANGUAGE
--> 194         self._language = LanguageTag(language)
    195         self.motherTongue = motherTongue
    196         self.disabled = set()

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in __new__(cls, tag)
    409     def __new__(cls, tag):
    410         # Can’t use super() here because of 3to2.
--> 411         return str.__new__(cls, cls._normalize(tag))
    412 
    413     def __eq__(self, other):

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in _normalize(cls, tag)
    429         if not tag:
    430             raise ValueError("empty language tag")
--> 431         languages = {l.lower().replace("-", "_"): l for l in get_languages()}
    432         try:
    433             return languages[tag.lower().replace("-", "_")]

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in get_languages()
    490         languages = cache["languages"]
    491     except KeyError:
--> 492         languages = LanguageTool._get_languages()
    493         cache["languages"] = languages
    494     return languages

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in _get_languages(cls)
    288         url = urllib.parse.urljoin(cls._url, "Languages")
    289         languages = set()
--> 290         for e in cls._get_root(url, num_tries=1):
    291             languages.add(e.get("abbr"))
    292             languages.add(e.get("abbrWithVariant"))

c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\language_tool\__init__.py in _get_root(cls, url, data, num_tries)
    314                     cls._start_server()
    315                 else:
--> 316                     raise Error("{}: {}".format(cls._url, e))
    317 
    318     @classmethod

Error: http://127.0.0.1:8081: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I've thoroughly consulted the documentation and have tried some other commands, all of which return the same error.

I've spent WAY too long figuring this out. Any help solving or troubleshooting would be super, super appreciated!